# Modeless Child WPF Window to a native MFC MDI Application

Tags: wpf, mfc, window, mdi, modeless

I have an MFC MDI application and I am trying to add a new dialog to it. I want this dialog to be in WPF (a Window basically rather than a dialog). This window should be modeless and a child to the current MDI View.

Let's say I have CMyView in the MFC application, and in its OnCreate, I try to create the WPF Window. To do so, I made a wrapper class called CMyWindowWrapper (that compiles with /CLR)

```
int CMyView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) 
{
  if (CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
    return -1;

  m_wrapper.Create(this);

  return 0;
}
```

The window wrapper class has a Create function which actually creates the WPF Window:

```
void CMyWindowWrapper::Create(CWnd* pParent)
{ 
   MyWindow^ window = gcnew MyWindow();

   window->ShowModeless((IntPtr)pParent->GetSafeHwnd());

   m_myWindow = window;
}
```

MyWindow is the WPF Window where I added a function called ShowModeless as follows:

```
public void ShowModeless(IntPtr parent)
 {
        WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
        helper.Owner = parent;

        Show();
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
 }
```

Now the application behaves as follows: whenever a CMyView is created, a modeless MyWindow is created successfully, and it appears always on top of CMyView even if the focus is on CMyView. However, when CMyView is closed or minimized, MyWindow is not following it. It gets close/minimized only if the whole application gets closed/minimized.

I can attach a sample application showing the problem if needed.

Please advise.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You might need to track the close/minimize events on CMyView and duplicate them manually on the wpf window.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to make your WPF window a user control. Create a MFC modeless dialog and put the WPF user control in the MFC modeless dialog.